# Taking a snapshot of an image with CSS3 filters flattened on top of the generated jpg

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm experimenting with the `getusermedia()` API to capture a snapshot from the users webcam. I'm then adding CSS3 filters to that snapshot.

What I would like to do is save that as a jpg with all the styles I've added to that image. Basically taking a screenshot of that particular styled div/image.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did on a project of mine. but sadly you have to use server side for that (I used php GD lib for that) just forward all the settings the user added to the pic and do the same on server side.

http://vintagejs.com/ is a good open source (https://github.com/rendro/vintageJS) project that maybe did it in a better way, but I don't sure.

Comment: did you check vintagejs? did they do it client-side?